# Luke says my Lucene index directory is Invalid

Tags: lucene, indexoutofboundsexception, luke

I'm trying to learn about Lucene, and hope to use Luke to investigate it.  I tried building an index with the IndexFiles demo in Lucene 4.3, then tried viewing the index with the latest version of Luke, and I'm getting the message:

```
Invalid directory at the location, check console for more information. Last exception:
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported (resource: ChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="/home/lavin/sep20.index/segments_2"))): 1 (needs to be between 0 and 0)
```

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix?   Is my version of Lucene too new for Luke to decipher?   Is there a way I can tell Lucene to write an older version of the index?   Thanks in advance, 
-- Mark

Answer (score 8):

you are probably using an older version of luke, the original maintainer no longer updates it to new versions of Lucene.

Get the latest from [this guy](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases/tag/4.6.0). He keeps it up to date.